# Complex roots of a ploynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Is there a way to find all the complex root for the polynomial $P(x)=(1+x+x^{2})^{n}$?

There must be $2n$ different complex roots given that the trinomial inside the brackets is of degree 2, am I right?

Comment: There are so many repeated roots. Can you see the relation between the roots of this polynomial, and of just $1+x+x^2$? Something to the power $n$ is zero if and only if it itself is zero, where $n\geq 1$ is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

To solve
$
(1+x+x^2)^n=
$
$ =\underbrace{(1+x+x^2)\cdot(1+x+x^2)\cdots(1+x+x^2)}_{n}=0
$

is the same as solve $1+x+x^2=0$ for $n$ times (product cancellation law).

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not right. There are only two roots ($-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i$), and each of them has multiplicity $n$.